# Efficient Descendant Record Deletion in MySQL, PHP, and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion, descendant

**What's the strategy for removing descendant records from a given record ID where the table points back to itself recursively?** Specifically I'm using PDO, PHP, and MySQL 5.0+.

Imagine a categories table with these columns:

- id
- parent_id
- category_name

If the ID is 0, then it's a root category. That id is not a primary key, mind you -- there can be many root categories.

Imagine it's several layers deep, like Food and Shelter root categories, and then children of those, and children of those, and so on. These are the descendants. If someone were to, say, delete Vegetables, then you could expect that Food and Shelter would be left behind as root categories, but Carrots would be gone, as would Beans. Mansions and Cabins would also be left behind because they are from another tree. Get it?

**EDIT**: My bad -- forgot a column -- parent_id. This is pretty critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the nested set model is more powerful, sometimes the following example with recursion can be good enough.

```
public function deleteCategory($sCatID) {
  if (empty($sCatID)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  // you can get your PDO database connection your own way -- this is my way for my framework
  $PDO = $this->data->mysql();
  // recursively find all the descendents of this category and delete those too
  $sSQL = "
  SELECT
    `id`
  FROM
    `categories`
  WHERE
    `parent_id` = :parent_id;
  ";
  $st = $PDO->prepare($sSQL);
  $st->bindValue(':parent_id',$sCatID);
  try {
    $st->execute();
    $rsRows = $st->fetchAll();
    foreach($rsRows as $rwRow) {
      $sChildCatID = $rwRow['id'];
      // note the recursion here!
      $this->deleteCategory($sChildCatID);
    }
  } catch (PDOException $e) {}
  unset($st);
  // now delete this category
  $sSQL = "
  DELETE FROM
    `categories`
  WHERE
    `id` = :id
  LIMIT 1;
  ";
  $st = $PDO->prepare($sSQL);
  $st->bindValue(':id',$sCatID);
  try {
    $st->execute();
  } catch (PDOException $e){}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not on option in your scenario, however, the nested set model for storing hierarchical data can make operations like the one you described very efficient.

Also this article might be useful:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

A simple cascading referential integrity should do it - declare your FOREIGN KEY with ON DELETE CASCADE. And if you index the `parent_id`, it should even be fairly efficient (this seems to be required in MySQL anyway; other DBMSes typically allow the index-less FK).

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    parent_id int DEFAULT NULL,
    category_name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    -- Will also create index on parent_id:
    CONSTRAINT your_table_fk1 FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES your_table (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO your_table (id, category_name) VALUES (1, 'Food');
INSERT INTO your_table (id, category_name) VALUES (2, 'Shelter');
INSERT INTO your_table (id, parent_id, category_name) VALUES (3, 1, 'Vegetables');
INSERT INTO your_table (id, parent_id, category_name) VALUES (4, 3, 'Carrots');
INSERT INTO your_table (id, parent_id, category_name) VALUES (5, 3, 'Beans');
INSERT INTO your_table (id, parent_id, category_name) VALUES (7, 2, 'Mansions');
INSERT INTO your_table (id, parent_id, category_name) VALUES (8, 2, 'Cabins');
```

Then when you execute...

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE category_name = 'Vegetables'
```

...not only 'Vegetables', but also 'Carrots' and 'Beans' will be deleted.

This even works recursively, so...

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE category_name = 'Food'
```

...deletes 'Food' at the first level, 'Vegetables' at the second and 'Carrots' and 'Beans' at the third.